# Video width on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, video, mobile, elementor

I added video in background section in Elementor plugin. On desktop it scales and works perfectly, but on mobile video is cropped and doesn't fit to screen.

I tried in chrome console set some values like max-width: 100%; width: auto; width: fit to content; and some other tips that I found in google (im still learning css)

I guess that's a part of CSS, where I should width but it doesn't work.

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.elementor-15 .elementor-element.elementor-element-1e70f52 {
    padding: 50px 30px 50px 30px;
}
```

I would like to make video width fit into device screen without being cropped.

Comment: use this for mobile size : `width: 100%; min-height: 100vh;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following media query format will help you. Put your video tag width and height size in the following media query.

```
<style>

/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {  

  /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

 }

 /* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

 }

 /* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

 } 

 /* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {  

  /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

 }      

 /* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

  /* Your CSS Code for this device size */ 

 }

 /* According to Mobile Orientation */
 @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {   

    /* Your CSS Code for this device orientation */    

 }

</style>
```